How to find Thévenin resistance
I'm trying to find the Thévenin resistance of the circuit below.
This is how I'm doing it. I opened the current source and closed the voltage source, hence the 20 Ω and 2 Ω resistors are in series and form a 22 Ω resistor. Now I'm not too sure whether the 12 Ω and the 22 Ω is in series or maybe in parallel.
Do we ignore the end bits of the terminal, do we not?
I'm new to this so any help is greatly appreciated. By the way the solution is 3 Ohms,


@Andyaka why not?

The 3Ω solution is correct.
The current source is a dependent type (the symbol doesn't reflect that, but the value does) so you can't just remove it to use superposition you have to write the equations.
However if you look at the circuit to the left of the 2 Ω resistor you can see it's equivalent to an independent 20V voltage source with 2Ω in series since the current through the 20Ω resistor is multiplied by 10. If that step is not obvious, write the equations - it's a more general approach.
So now we can replace the 20V source with 0Ω and the Thévenin resistance is (2Ω + 2Ω)||12Ω = 3Ω.

Hint:
Replace voltage source with short circuit. Leave the dependent current source as it is. Look from the output terminals. Ground the bottom terminal at output. Connect a DC 1A current source between top and bottom terminals at output. Use nodal analysis to calculate voltage \$V_{out}\$ at output That would give Thevenin resistance of the network.

Removing current sources is not a valid approach if those sources are dependent.

Yes, you are right. If they are dependent , current or voltage sources cannot be removed. I will change the answer.

Welcome. Yes replacing voltage sources by short and current sources with open circuit is correct. One way to determine the Thevenin resistance can be done by applying a test voltage (Vt) at the wanted terminals and find the input current (It). Taking the ration of this gives the input resistance: Rth = Vt/It.

Find \$ V_{th} \$: which is  basically the voltage across the \$ 12 \Omega \$ :

the circuit is open on the RHS : \$20 V = 20 \Omega \cdot I + (2 \Omega+ 12 \Omega) \cdot 10 I \iff V_{th} = 1.5 V\$
the circuit is shorted on the RHS lets find \$ I_{th} \$ :
\$ 20 V  = 20 \Omega \cdot I + 2\Omega \cdot 10I \iff I_{th} = 0.5 V\$

Finally \$R_{th} = \frac{V_{th}}{I_{th}} = 3 \Omega \$
